# To call a network API repeatedly in Android app in Foreground

Tags: android, job-scheduling

I want to call a network API repeated for every 20 seconds when app is in Foreground, I tried achieving this through job Scheduler

```html
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(getActivity(), TcApiLogService.class);
        JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(12, componentName)
                 .setPeriodic(20000)
                .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED)
                .build();
```

but job scheduler restricts from Android N to schedule jobs only once in 15 mins.

I know this can be achieved by handler but any one can pass on other better approach to solve this problem.

Comment: does remote data change every 20 seconds? or you are checking remote api and in most cases the data is the same?

Comment: I would be writing series of instructions in a local file within 20 seconds period, after which i try to post the same to server after 20s.

Answer (score 1):

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
   @Override public void run(){
    //here call request
   }
};
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 20000);// 20000 ms
```